# drawing more on the canvas without having to create more script tags

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've been attempting to create a ecology simulation and so far its been going good. The code below does work I'm just wondering if theres an easier way to draw more items on the canvas with code instead of manually doing it. The way I'm doing it makes me consider the lag because I will be adding a lot to the code (e.g. move, detected, reproduce, chase, run, etc). Thank you for seeing this

```js
//This tag will regulate the spawning of new sheep/wolves
var totalWolves = 0;
var totalSheep = 0;
var canavs = document.getElementById("canvas");
var body = document.getElementById("body");

//styler
body.style.overflow = "hidden";
body.style.margin = "0px";
canvas.style.backgroundColor = "black";

function spawnWolves(){
 totalWolves++;
 var name = "wolf" + totalWolves;
 var scrpt = document.createElement("SCRIPT");
 document.body.appendChild(scrpt);
 scrpt.setAttribute("id", name);
 var script = document.getElementById(name);
 script.innerHTML = "var rand3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1; var rand4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1; var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'); var context = canvas.getContext('2d'); context.fillStyle = 'red'; context.fillRect(rand3, rand4, 10, 10); context.fill();";
 
}
spawnWolves();
spawnWolves();
spawnWolves();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>AI spawn test</title>
</head>
<body id="body">
<canvas id="canvas" width="1366px" height="768px"/>
<script>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution seems very complicated ...

Please, take a look at the following code.

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <title>AI spawn test</title>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="110" height="110"></canvas>
  <script>
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var drawRect=function(rects){
    for (var i=1; i<=rects; i++){
      var rand3=Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
      var rand4=Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
      ctx.fillStyle='red';
      ctx.fillRect(rand3, rand4, 10, 10)
    }
  }
  drawRect(20);
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This type of 'replication' is done by using `loop`. There are several loop types, but their explanation is too broad. You can browse the net.

I gave you 2 examples below - with `for` loop and with `while` loop.

```js
//This tag will regulate the spawning of new sheep/wolves
var totalWolves = 0;
var totalSheep = 0;
var canavs = document.getElementById("canvas");
var body = document.getElementById("body");

//styler
body.style.overflow = "hidden";
body.style.margin = "0px";
canvas.style.backgroundColor = "black";

function spawnWolves(){
 totalWolves++;
 var name = "wolf" + totalWolves;
 var scrpt = document.createElement("SCRIPT");
 document.body.appendChild(scrpt);
 scrpt.setAttribute("id", name);
 var script = document.getElementById(name);
 script.innerHTML = "var rand3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1; var rand4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1; var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'); var context = canvas.getContext('2d'); context.fillStyle = 'red'; context.fillRect(rand3, rand4, 10, 10); context.fill();";
 
}

for(var i=0; i<12; i++)
{
    spawnWolves();
}

var maxWolves=9;
while(totalWolves < maxWolves)
{
    spawnWolves();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>AI spawn test</title>
</head>
<body id="body">
<canvas id="canvas" width="1366px" height="768px"/>
<script>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The first loop will run until its internal counter `i` goes from 0 to 12 and will call the function exactly 12 times.

The second loop will run as long as the condition `totalWolves < maxWolves` is true. `totalWolves` is your counter you increase in your function and `maxWolves` is the limit when you want the loop to stop.

*Because these 2 examples are added here one after another the second wont work. After the first one executes you will already have 12 wolves and the second loop will not enter because `12 < 9` is false.*

Comment: Note your second loop wont do anything as there is already 12 wolves

Comment: Thanks, I know, but I will add explanation for OP.